# Reinstall MESA driver

Tags: mesa

I'm new here and will be thankful if you help me in this case.
I dunno why, but somehow I did upgrade video driver and now I want to restore the original one for current system.
Is this safe and is it work if remove/purge libraries one by one, and then install them again with commands like that:

```
$sudo aptitude remove libegl-mesa0:amd64
$sudo aptitude install libegl-mesa0:amd64
```

So I want to remove these which are 18.3~git to the
18.0.5

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mesa            
libegl-mesa0:amd64   18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libegl1-mesa:amd64   18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64   18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 
libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64    18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64    18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386    18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64    18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386    18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libglapi-mesa:amd64    18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libglapi-mesa:i386   18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b  
libgles2-mesa:amd64   18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64   18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 
libglu1-mesa:amd64     9.0.0-2.1build1 
libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64  9.0.0-2.1build1 
libglx-mesa0:amd64   18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libglx-mesa0:i386   18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64  18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 
mesa-common-dev:amd64   18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 
mesa-opencl-icd:i386  18.0.5-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 
mesa-utils  8.4.0-1 
mesa-va-drivers:amd64  18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b 
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64  18.3~git1810131930.b7397b~oibaf~b
```

Comment: The following answer is somewhat related. However, the specific versions mentioned are different so the exact commands used will not work but you can get an idea on how safe or unsafe it may be based on how much work you want to do. https://askubuntu.com/questions/908064/dependency-problem-while-removing-oibaf-and-paulo-dias-repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the package names, or from something like `apt-cache policy mesa-va-drivers | grep -C2 Version`, we can see these packages come from the **Oibaf** repository.

To revert to the default packages you need to `ppa-purge` those repos.

`sudo apt install ppa-purge`
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

Should revert you to the default repos and install the default packages.

In my experience the Oibaf and PKPPA repos do go bad sometimes, but usually are back to being usable within a couple of days. If it's just the latest updates that have gone wrong then it's possible to backtrack to prior versions (GUI tool Synaptic, and CLI too Aptitude both are good for that).

Comment: See here on how to revert after using ppa-purge: https://askubuntu.com/questions/112865/how-do-i-revert-all-packages-to-their-official-versions

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys! It was helpful! This is what I've did:
First checks all packages contains **oibaf**

```
$ dpkg -l | grep oibaf
```

Then I checks for recommended version

```
$ apt policy <package-name>
```

And finally does install with specific version

```
$ sudo aptitude install <package-name>=version
```

Voiala, no more oibaf. My end goal was to upgrade system to 18.10 cosmic and it's done